# How to design database table for keeping track of price changes

Tags: mysql

I want to store stock market data in MySQL. There are some 100 individual stocks to store. Each has the following data:

Basically my requriment is that i want to know  what is the change of price in Stock for every 5 mins from my DataBase (MYSQL)

For example , initially i will store the data of a Stock , say ABCD this way

```
Symbol   Price         change_price
ABCD      222.00      210.00
```

So that i can get the information as that Stock ABCD has gone down 12 points within 5 minutes

How to design the table for such thing ??

Comment: I would store a list of prices at set times and then the change can be calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with churchwalk's comment.

For each symbol, the key information would be: **price** and **change_time**.  Then then variance can be calculated.